# How to update in nodejs using sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I want to update the wallet table when I deposit an amount in the wallet.

My code is like this:

model wallet.js

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    var Model = sequelize.define('wallet', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            field: 'id',
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        cid: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            field: 'cid'
        },
        deposit: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            field: 'deposit'
        },
        withdrawal: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            field: 'withdrawal'
        },
        available: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            field: 'available',
        },
        comments: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            field: 'comments'
        },
        online: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            field: 'online'
        }
    }, {
        tableName: 'wallet',
        timestamps: false
    });
    Model.associate = function (models) {
        this.orders = this.hasOne(models.orders, {
            as: 'orders',
            foreignKey: 'wid'
        });
    };

    Model.prototype.toWeb = function (pw) {
        let json = this.toJSON();
        return json;
    };
    return Model;
};
```

here the wallet deposit is happening here i am using set method to update the wallet

```
   walletcontroller.js

const deposit = async function (req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let err, wallet, existingWallet;
    let wallet_info = req.body;
    [err, existingWallet] = await to(Wallet.findAll({
        limit: 1,
        where: {
            cid: wallet_info.cid,
        },
        order: [
            ['id', 'DESC']
        ]
    }));
    [err, wallet] = await to(Wallet.set(wallet_info, {
        limit: 1,
        where: {
            cid: wallet_info.cid,
        },
        order: [
            ['id', 'DESC']
        ]
    }));
    if (err) return ReE(res, err, 422);
    if (existingWallet[0] != 'undefined') {
        wallet.available = existingWallet[0].available + wallet_info.deposit;
        wallet.comments = new Date();
    } else {
        wallet.available = wallet_info.deposit;
        wallet.comments = new Date();
    }
    console.log("avalible balance:" + wallet.available);
    [err, wallet] = await to(wallet.save());
    if (err) return ReE(res, err, 422);
    return ReS(res, {
        wallet: wallet.toWeb()
    }, 201);
}
module.exports.deposit = deposit;
```

please help me out how to update the wallet... when i am callig api here my err msg looks like this

```
     Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `cid`, `deposit`, `withdrawal`, `available`, `comments`, `online` FROM `wallet` AS `wallet` WHERE `wallet`.`cid` = '33' ORDER BY `wallet`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1;
```

**Error:**

```
Uncaught Error { filename: '\\cl-api-master\\controllers\\WalletController.js',
  line: 67,
  row: 37,
  message: 'Wallet.set is not a function',
  type: 'TypeError',
  stack: 'TypeError: Wallet.set is not a function\n    at deposit (E:\\cl-api-master\\controllers\\WalletController.js:67:37)\n    at <anonymous>',
  arguments: undefined }
POST /v1/wallet/deposit - - ms - -
```

Comment: What's the line "await to(Wallet.set(wallet_info, {" does? I think there is no .set function available for models.

Comment: how to update the model when i deposit the amount

Answer (score 0):

For Edition, you can simply use -

```
data.update = await Wallet.update(
        {
            available: available,
            comments: new Date()
        },
        {
            where: { cid: wallet_info.cid }
        }
);
```

**available** variable can be set using if else condition afterward running above update query.

Comment: wallet = await Wallet.update(wallet_info,      
        {
            where: { cid: wallet_info.cid }
        });

Comment: after adding these lines my error is Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `cid`, `deposit`, `withdrawal`, `available`, `comments`, `online` FROM `wallet` AS `wallet` WHERE `wallet`.`cid` = '33' ORDER BY `wallet`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1;
Executing (default): UPDATE `wallet` SET `cid`='33',`deposit`=25 WHERE `cid` = '33'
avalible balance:53562075
[ 0,
  available: 53562075,
  comments: 2019-03-16T09:47:19.723Z ]
Uncaught Error { filename: '\\cl-api-master\\controllers\\WalletController.js',
  line: 86,
  row: 37,
  message: 'wallet.save is not a function',
  type: 'TypeError',

Comment: Please share your whole function on which error is coming

Comment: Please see - https://pastebin.com/2fUhEaBH Feel free to ask any queries you may have

Comment: rohit it updates the entire available balance in database but i want to update the last entry of the wallet table using cid..

Comment: I changed the findAll to findOne, can use the findAll and orderBy attribute to get the last value and update it. Just like in your old old code. Only change is FindAll and use of [0] ot access the param